# Python: Unpacking an inner nested tuple/list while still getting its index number

Tags: python, list, tuples, enumerate, iterable-unpacking

I am familiar with using `enumerate()`:

```
>>> seq_flat = ('A', 'B', 'C')
>>> for num, entry in enumerate(seq_flat):
        print num, entry
0 A
1 B
2 C
```

I want to be able to do the same for a nested list:

```
>>> seq_nested = (('A', 'Apple'), ('B', 'Boat'), ('C', 'Cat'))
```

I can unpack it with:

```
>>> for letter, word in seq_nested:
        print letter, word
A Apple
B Boat
C Cat
```

How should I unpack it to get the following?

```
0 A Apple
1 B Boat
2 C Cat
```

The only way I know is to use a counter/incrementor, which is un-Pythonic as far as I know. Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: For the record, what you have there are tuples, not lists. Lists use `[]`, tuples use `(,)`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
for i, (letter, word) in enumerate(seq_nested):
  print i, letter, word
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes