# How to iterate over Pandas Series generated from groupby().size()

Tags: python, pandas

How do you iterate over a Pandas Series generated from a `.groupby('...').size()` command and get both the group name and count.

As an example if I have:

```
foo
-1     7
 0    85
 1    14
 2     5
```

how can I loop over them so that in each iteration I would have -1 & 7, 0 & 85, 1 & 14 and 2 & 5 in variables?

I tried the enumerate option but it doesn't quite work.  Example:

```
for i, row in enumerate(df.groupby(['foo']).size()):
    print(i, row)
```

it doesn't return -1, 0, 1, and 2 for `i` but rather 0, 1, 2, 3.

Comment: enumerate just calculates the number of item in any sequence, it knows nothing about internal index of Series, that is why it is just 0, 1, 2, 3 and will be the same for any iterable

Comment: Most numeric operations with pandas can be vectorized - this means they are much faster than conventional iteration. OTOH, some operations (such as string and regex) are inherently hard to vectorize. This this case, it is important to understand _how_ to loop over your data. More more information on when and how looping over your data is to be done, please read [For loops with Pandas - When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care/54028200#54028200).

Answer (score 132, accepted):

**Update**:

Given a pandas Series:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

s
#a    1
#b    2
#c    3
#d    4
#dtype: int64
```

You can directly loop through it, which yield one value from the series in each iteration:

```
for i in s:
    print(i)
1
2
3
4
```

If you want to access the index at the same time, you can use either `items` or `iteritems` method, which produces a generator that contains both the index and value:

```
for i, v in s.items():
    print('index: ', i, 'value: ', v)
#index:  a value:  1
#index:  b value:  2
#index:  c value:  3
#index:  d value:  4

for i, v in s.iteritems():
    print('index: ', i, 'value: ', v)
#index:  a value:  1
#index:  b value:  2
#index:  c value:  3
#index:  d value:  4
```

---

**Old Answer**:

You can call `iteritems()` method on the Series:

```
for i, row in df.groupby('a').size().iteritems():
    print(i, row)

# 12 4
# 14 2
```

According to doc:

> Series.iteritems()
>
> Lazily iterate over (index, value) tuples

Note: This is not the same data as in the question, just a demo.

Comment: That's the solution I was looking for - thanks.  I had tried `.iterrows()` but it did not provide the solution I was looking for.

Comment: `iterrows()` is the method for data frame and for Series, `iteritems()` works.

Comment: `iteritems()` is [deprecated in Pandas 1.5](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.Series.iteritems.html) and removed since 2.0, [there is only `items()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/2.1/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html)

Answer (score 11):

To expand upon the answer of Psidom, there are three useful ways to unpack data from pd.Series. Having the same Series as Psidom:

`s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])`

- A direct loop over `s` yields the `value` of each row.
- A loop over
  `s.iteritems()` or `s.items()` yields a tuple with the `(index,value)`
  pairs of each row.
- Using `enumerate()` on `s.iteritems()` yields a
  nested tuple in the form of: `(rownum,(index,value))`.

The last way is useful in case your index contains other information than the row number itself (e.g. in a case of a timeseries where the index is time).

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

for rownum,(indx,val) in enumerate(s.iteritems()):
    print('row number: ', rownum, 'index: ', indx, 'value: ', val)
```

will output:

```
row number:  0 index:  a value:  1
row number:  1 index:  b value:  2
row number:  2 index:  c value:  3
row number:  3 index:  d value:  4
```

You can read more on unpacking nested tuples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331643/python-unpacking-an-inner-nested-tuple-list-while-still-getting-its-index-numbe).