# how to write list comprehension for selecting cells base on a substring

Tags: pandas, substring, list-comprehension

I am trying to rewrite the following in one line using list comprehension. I want to select cells that contains substring '[edit]' only. ut is my dataframe and the column that I want to select from is 'col1'. Thanks!

```
    for u in ut['col1']:
        if '[edit]' in u:
            print(u)

I expect the following output:
Alabama[edit]
Alaska[edit]
Arizona[edit]
...
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55335207/4909087), scroll down to "A Great Alternative: Use List Comprehensions!"

Comment: @ChrisA I tried that and i got a syntax error. i think it has to do with the ordering of  'u in ut['col1'] with the list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

If the output of a Pandas `Series` is acceptable, then you can just use [`.str.contains`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55127377/4057186), without a loop

```
s = ut[ut["col1"].str.contains("edit")]
```

If you need to print each element of the `Series` separately, then loop over the `Series` [using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38387640/4057186)

```
for i in s:
    print(i)
```