# How do you turn a tuple with three elements into a dictionary containing a key and two values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a tuple that looks like this:

```
List=[
    ('actinium-225', '10', '314'), 
    ('actinium-226', '1.2238', '110'), 
    ('americium-240', '2.117', '395'), 
    ('berkelium-245', '4.94', '182'),
]
```

The list goes on, anyways so I've been searching how to unpack these to create a dictionary so that I can calculate the radioactive decay rates of these elements given the first value is the element, the second being the half life and third the remaining stock quantity (in grams).

I need something like this

```
Dict={
    1: ('actinium 225', 10, 314), 
    2: ('actinium-226', 1.2238, 110), 
    3: ('americium-240', 2.117, 395),
    4: ('berkelium-245', 4.94, 182),
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a `dict` if your keys are just `int` numbers? Continue using a `list` instead.

Comment: yeah... well this assignment that was dropped on us in CHEM  requires us to write and test the elemental radioactive decay formula in python and i figured that dict might be the best method...BTW none of us have experience in Py

Answer (score 1):

> How do you turn a tuple with three elements into a dictionary
> containing ***a key and two values***?

Your question title doesn't match your expected output, so I'll just go with the expected output rather than question title.

You can use `map` and `enumerate` with Dictionary Comprehension:

```py
{idx: tuple([item[0]] + list(map(float, item[1:]))) for idx, item in enumerate(List, 1)}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
{1: ('actinium-225', 10.0, 314.0),
 2: ('actinium-226', 1.2238, 110.0),
 3: ('americium-240', 2.117, 395.0),
 4: ('berkelium-245', 4.94, 182.0)}
```

*If no type cast required, you can just do* `dict(enumerate(List,1))`

Comment: @dontaccept , initially I wanted to post answer with dict comprehension `{i:v for i, v in enumerate(item, 1)}` (no map required). Hovewer `dict(enumerate(item,1))` is much shorter

Comment: I usually prefer comprehension though @Georgiy

Comment: Nice answer, but `map` is unnecesary there. You can do a [nested unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331643/python-unpacking-an-inner-nested-tuple-list-while-still-getting-its-index-numbe), see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
dic = {}
for index, ele in enumerate(List):
    key = index+1
    val_2 = float(ele[1])
    val_3 = int(ele[2])
    dic.update({key: (ele[0], val_2, val_3)})
    
print(dic)

{1: ('actinium-225', 10.0, 314), 2: ('actinium-226', 1.2238, 110), 3: ('americium-240', 2.117, 395), 4: ('berkelium-245', 4.94, 182)}
```

Comment: im using Python 3.8.6 and its not running. what version is yours?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to you question is trivial, you can transform your iterable as much as you want with tools like comprehension, generated expressions, map / filter, whatever you prefer.

This one is kind of a code-golf for that:

```
Dict = {i: (el, float(hl), int(st)) for i, (el, hl, st) in enumerate(List, 1)}
```

---

**HOWEVER**,

I honestly don't see the point. If you think you need a dictionary whose keys are just ordered `int` numbers, **you don't need a `dict`, you need a `list`**!

And you already have them in a `list`. You can retrieve the values by index like `List[2]`, much like (and even better) than retrieving them from a `dict`, like `Dict[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through the tuple and create a dictionary, like this

```
elements = [('actinium-225', '10', '314'), ('actinium-226', '1.2238', '110'), ('americium-240', '2.117', '395'), ('berkelium-245', '4.94', '182')]
elemDict = {}
for ind, tup in enumerate(elements):
    elemDict[ind+1] = tup
```

Comment: thanks but im using Python 3.8.6 and its not running. what version is yours?

Comment: @BuzzKotta this should work in python 3.8, are you getting an error ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple `for-loop` with `enumerate` and `data destruction`:

```py
l = [
    ('actinium-225', '10', '314'), 
    ('actinium-226', '1.2238', '110'), 
    ('americium-240', '2.117', '395'), 
    ('berkelium-245', '4.94', '182'),
]
d = {}
for i, (a, b, c) in enumerate(l, 1):
    d[i] = (a, float(b), int(c))

print(d)
'''
{1: ('actinium-225', 10.0, 314), 
 2: ('actinium-226', 1.2238, 110),
 3: ('americium-240', 2.117, 395),
 4: ('berkelium-245', 4.94, 182)}
'''
```